# Getting background colour-changing buttons to work

Tags: html, css

I know there's probably a lot wrong with this but I'm just drafting for a school assignment.

Script:

```
  a.button4;{
    text-align; center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration; none;
    font-size; 17px;
    font-family;'Roboto',sans-serifZ
    color:"white";
}
a.button4;hover{
 border-color; rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
</script>
```

Div:

```
<div style='float: right;'>
     <a href="" class="button4" style="background-color:#f14e4e"></a>
     <a href="" class="button4" style="background-color:#f1bb4e"></a>
     <a href="" class="button4" style="background-color:#84f14e"></a>
     <a href="" class="button4" style="background-color:#4ef18f"></a>
     <a href="" class="button4" style="background-color:#4e9af1"></a>
     <a href="" class="button4" style="background-color:#9a4ef1"></a>
     <a href="" class="button4" style="background-color:#f14ebd"></a>
      </div>
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: R u  using css styles propertiees in the script tag of ?

Comment: If So then move that in to <style></style> tag .

Comment: Maybe it is the semicolon after "button4" in the css file. It should be a.button4:hover, if I am not mistaken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a simple HTML code and I used your colors.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>
    a.button4{ background-color:#f14e4e; }
    a.button5{ background-color:#f1bb4e; }
    a.button6{ background-color:#84f14e; }
    a.button7{ background-color:#4ef18f; }
    a.button8{ background-color:#4e9af1; }
    #test{ background-color:#9a4ef1; }
    #btn1{ background-color:#f14ebd }
    </style>
    <head>
        <!--you can add your css here, or you can write your css in style as I wrote above-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style='float: right;'>
             <a href="" class="button4">Link 1</a>
             <a href="" class="button5">Link 2</a>
             <a href="" class="button6">Link 3</a>
             <a href="" class="button7">Link 4</a>
             <a href="" class="button8">Link 5</a>
        </div>
        <br />
        <!--you also can make a buttons-->
         <div style='float: right;'>
            <input type="button" name="test" id="test" class="button" value="My button">
             <button type="button" name="btn1" id="btn1">Button 2</button>
         </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
/* CSS rules is `property-name: value;` and in when you start css class name dosen't end with `;` */
a.button4 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serifZ;
    color: white;
}
a.button4:hover{
    background-color : rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
```

```html
<!-- Here I use Display flex instant of float right -->
<div style="display:flex;">
     <a href="" class="button4" style="background-color:#f14e4e"></a>
     <a href="" class="button4" style="background-color:#f1bb4e"></a>
     <a href="" class="button4" style="background-color:#84f14e"></a>
     <a href="" class="button4" style="background-color:#4ef18f"></a>
     <a href="" class="button4" style="background-color:#4e9af1"></a>
     <a href="" class="button4" style="background-color:#9a4ef1"></a>
     <a href="" class="button4" style="background-color:#f14ebd"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The style attribute has a **MUCH** higher specificity than the selector you're using in your stylesheets.

Also double check where you're using `;` vs. `:`. In your first rule, the selector does not need to end with a `;`.

Inside of your CSS rules, it should go `property-name: value;`.
With pseudo-elements and pseudo-classes, you should use `:` e.g. `a.button4:hover`.

The [batificity](http://batificity.com/) guide helped me understand specificity a lot better when I first started with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

ok, here are some fixes to your code, first put your styles under `style` tag not in `script` tag, other issues are with colons and  semicolons, I will provide code below:

```
<style>
a.button4{
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 17px;
font-family:'Roboto',sans-serifZ
color:"white";
}
a.button4:hover{
border-color; rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
</style>
```